# Check a checkbox and get its sibling from listview row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a C#, WPF ListView that has checkbox and a string in each row. When I click the checkbox, I want it be able to get the sibling string that is in the same row but I don't quite know how. I'm a WPF noob.

I have my columns bound to the properties of an incoming object called Row that has a Name and a boolean that indicates whether or not it is active.

It's almost like I need to walk up the visual tree to get the "row" and then grab the child that is not a checkbox.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. XAML below.

mj

```
        <ListView Name="CompanyListView" Width="300" Height="200">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="25">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Active}" Click="CompanyCheckboxClicked"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="250"/>                      
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Do you need to grab the corresponding Name each time a checkbox is selected, or allow the user to select the checkbox of multiple rows, then grab the Name values for each row selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CheckBox's [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) should contain the Row object.

```
private void CompanyCheckboxClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
    Row row = checkBox.DataContext as Row;
    ...
}
```

Comment: If this Answer help pls, @mj_, check it like Correct